# Complex Mongo query, checking simultaneously on several attributes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Here is what my database could look like :

```
[
    {
        _id       : xxx,
        languages : [
            { lang: "French",  level: 1 },
            { lang: "English", level: 3 },
            { lang: "Spanish", level: 4 }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id       : yyy,
        languages : [
            { lang: "French",  level: 5 },
            { lang: "English", level: 2 }
       ]
    }
]
```

I have that kind of list :

```
[
    {
        lang  : "French",
        cmp   : "at least",
        level : 3
    },
    {
        lang  : "English",
        cmp   : "at most",
        level : 2
    }
]
```

My goal is to build a query that, with this example :

- Select all the users who speaks French with a level >=
- AND who speaks English with a level <= 2
- the selected users can have others languages for which I do not care

In other words, I want to build a query that finds every users who have ALL the languages specified in the list, each languages having to match the level comparison to be valid.

It's kinda hard, as I'm not used to such complex queries in MongoDB.

Currently, I'm not looking for level comparison. I just query for the users matching the good languages, no matter the level, using `"profile.languages.lang" : { $all: languagesArray }`, with `languagesArray` a list of strings I get with a .map on my comparison's object list.

My problem is that I don't know how to spevify so much constraints on a single attribute / list of my document. Of course, I could fetch to refine my search, but it would be really costly over time, as my database is growing pretty fast.

Could anyone guide me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Users.find({
  $or: [
    {
      languages: {
        $elemMatch: {
          lang: 'French',
          level: { $gte: 2 }
        },
      }
    },
    {
      languages: {
        $elemMatch: {
          lang: 'English',
          level: { $lte: 2 }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}).fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks you, it is really simplier than I thought !
I'm going to save a huge amount of time on my next release :)